# Create mfx video file from a list images using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

Is it possible to create `mfx` (IMX) file by merging a list of images and a single audio file using `ffmpeg`?

I checked many blog/posts but could not find anything.

I know i can create mp4s from images and audio so was wondering if there's anything similar for `mfx`?

Comment: I don't know off the hand whether ffmpeg supports `mfx` format, but the methods you found to generate mp4 applies to any video format. Try by just changing `output.mp4` to `output.mfx`. If it doesn't work, the error message will tell you if it's because `mfx` is not supported

Comment: I already tried by using the command I use for mp4s but I always get some sort of problems. Here `ffmpeg -i ./frames/frame_%04d.png -i ./audio/finalAudio.mp3 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -shortest -color_primaries 5 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 6 ./test-3.mp4` is the command I use for mp4s.

Comment: Post the ffmpeg log, too. Add details on your post by editing it instead of as comments